# Spring Boot does not resolve environment variable in external property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am starting spring boot project as follows

```
java -classpath "/home/madhur/github/fantasy_fury/target/fantasy_fury.jar:/home/madhur/github/fantasy_fury/target/dependency/*:/home/madhur/github/fantasy_fury/conf" com.games24x7.fantasy.fury.FantasyFuryInit
```

The conf folder has an `application.properties` with following contnents

```
zkHost=${ZK_CLUSTER_URLS}
```

Now, I am trying to read this variable as follows:

```
   @Value("${zkHost:localhost}")
    String zkHost;
```

However, it does not contain the actual value, but the default value `localhost` value every time.

Tried to set it as follows:

```
 export ZK_CLUSTER_URLS=madhur1;java -classpath "/home/madhur/github/fantasy_fury/target/fantasy_fury.jar:/home/madhur/github/fantasy_fury/target/dependency/*:/home/madhur/github/fantasy_fury/conf" com.games24x7.fantasy.fury.FantasyFuryInit
```

Then also, the output is `localhost`. What I am missing?

Spring boot version is 1.4

Comment: As it is a directory shouldn't it end with a `/`... Also does your application contain an `application.properties` as well? If so this won't work.

Comment: It does seem to pick up the changes If I just put up the hard coded value so the / doesnt matter as far as I know.

Comment: What do you mean with hardcoded value in this case?

Comment: Also have you tried specifying it as a system parameter with -D to java.